# how do I create a signature for the executeAllowanceTransfer function in safe modules AllowanceModule?

Tags: ethereum, gnosis-safe

I am trying to create a signature that is accepted by the `executeAllowanceTransfer` function. I can't workout how to generate a signature that is approved in the allowance as I keep getting the return error message of `"expectedDelegate == signer && delegates[address(safe)][uint48(signer)].delegate == signer"`

Allowance module can be found here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules/blob/47e2b486b0b31d97bab7648a3f76de9038c6e67b/allowances/contracts/AlowanceModule.sol

I've tried to send a signature generated by passing `transferHash` into `signer.signMessage` via ethers.

Answer (score 0):

use `0x` as signature parameter

```
const executeTxResponse = await allowanceContract?.executeAllowanceTransfer('0xB91...B032E', '0x66...aF2, '0x345...Df5A', '1000000000000000000', '0x0000..0000', '0', '0x445...F404', '0x')
```

Comment: thanks. tried that and keep getting "transaction reverted" error. perhaps my issue is something else.

Comment: know what the best way to debug such things are? "transaction reverted" is a pretty poor error response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).